# Addition of a list until sum matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, addition

I want to add up a specific list of numbers (1,2,3,4,5,...) until the sum matches a given variable. For example for the number 24 the solution would be 5: 1+1,2+2,3+3,4+4,5+5

I don´t know how to solve it, because I have not much experience with python. I tried it with

```
x= 24
sum = 0
i = 1
while i <= X:
sum = sum + i
i = i + 1
print(i)
```

but this prints only all numbers until 24. Other attempts for example with "for i in range()" also doesn´t work.

Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code

Comment: 1+1,2+2,3+3,4+4,5+5 relates to 24 how exactly?

Comment: it is the addition to match 24

Comment: also note that you have both `x` and `X`

Comment: You say you want to sum a list of numbers, then give an example that isn't a sum and neither of them seem to have any relation to 24. Can you give more specific requirements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add items in a list until their sum exceeds a threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329194/add-items-in-a-list-until-their-sum-exceeds-a-threshold)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
end = 24
sum = 1
step = 1

while sum <= end:
    sum += (2 * i)
    step += 1

print(step - 1)
```

Comment: There is not a more pythonic way of doing it? I was actually searching for a pythonic and efficient approach to the above problem.