# Add items in a list until their sum exceeds a threshold

Tags: python, list, sum

From a list of values I want to create a new list of values until they add up a value.

I am new with Python but I believe it is best done with a while loop.

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
i = 0
s = 0
while i < len(L) and s + L[i] < 20:
    s += L[i]
    i += 1
```

Comment: Works. What's the question?

Comment: i don't get the problem itself, what do you want to do?

Comment: I think he wants a list with the values that sum upto that limit.

Comment: Your new list is `L[:i]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`numpy` arrays make this simple

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(L)
arr[arr.cumsum() <= 20].tolist()
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: FYI, will fail if first element is greater than or equal to 20

Comment: probably the cleanest to write but can't imagine it's more efficient than what's proposed above given in this example you're doing the cumulative sum of all elements without a stopping condition whereas the above does have one.

Comment: If the first element in the list is >= 20, it returns an empty list, which IMO is the correct answer as even indicating the first element would exceed the threshold. As for the efficiency, numpy calculations are all vectorized, it's not a loop. If you have a list where you'd need to loop over 100k elements to reach the threshold a while loop is going to be unecessarily slow compared to the vectorized cumsum and Boolean slicing.

Answer (score 5):

Since you tagged Pandas:

```
pd.Series(L, index=np.cumsum(L)).loc[:20].values
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 4):

You first create the empty list, and then append values with the same conditions you stated. Finally printing the list will return you the values that got added that match your criteria:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
i = 0
s = 0
new_list = []
while i < len(L) and s + L[i] < 20:
    new_list.append(L[i])
    s += L[i]
    i += 1
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I find this answer superior than the rest, the accepted answer is a ton of pointless iterations, ( since you store the current sum, you only need to look at the next step, the accepted answer doesn't store the total sum and at every step does the exact same iteration from zero to i at every iteration. The other answer that uses cumsum is better but cumsum is also inefficient as you only need the sum until a certain threshold whereas cumsum performs the calculation on the whole array. This answer isn't doing pointless calculations.

Answer (score -1):

If you would sum from start to end the (imo) more pythonic way would be

```
s = 0
for element in L:
   if s + element < 20:
         s += element
    else:
         break
```

Comment: Supplemental: `for` and `if` lower case please - don't you test your code before posting...?

Comment: I adressed your concerns, and no in this case i just dumped it out from my phone hence the auto corrected capitals

Comment: I know that - really annoying that auto correction, although I have to say I have the same issue on the desktop machine... Regarding testing: I'm also often here via mobile and really can recommend _Pydroid 3_.

Comment: Thx I'll check it out

Answer (score -1):

You can easily write your own generator function:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def takeuntil(lst, max_value = 0):
    """Yields elements as long as the cummulative sum is smaller than max_value."""
    total = 0
    for item in lst:
        total += item
        if total <= max_value:
            yield item
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    raise StopIteration

new_lst = [item for item in takeuntil(L, 20)]
print(new_lst)
```

Which yields

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```