# How can I count how many numbers can be fitted within particular number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example 1:

```
save([4,4,4,3,3], 12) -> 3
# 4+4+4 <= 12, but 4+4+4+3 > 12
```

Example 2:

```
save([4,4,4,3,3], 11) -> 2
# 4+4 <= 11, but 4+4+4 > 11
```

First of all I'm noob yet, but here is my "code" lol.

```
def save(sizes, hd): 
    sum = 0
    for i in sizes:
        sum = sum + i
        if sum <= hd:
            a = (str(sum))
            print(a)   

save([4,4,4,3,3], 12)
```

Output of this code is:

```
4 
8 
12
```

It would be correct if I could count length of those numbers, but I tried many ways and still couldnt found(

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not really clear on the algorithm. `save([4,4,4,3,3], 11) -> 2`, it seems like we can pick 4,4,3 and return 3, or is it only contiguous from the start of the array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add items in a list until their sum exceeds a threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329194/add-items-in-a-list-until-their-sum-exceeds-a-threshold)

Answer (score 1):

You need the [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
def save(sizes, hd): 
    summm = 0
    for index,value in enumerate(sizes,1):  # start counting at 1
        summm += value
        if summm <= hd: 
            print(summm, index)    # or simply print index alone

save([4,4,4,3,3], 12)
```

Outputs:

```
 12 3   # first number is the sum, second amount of numbers you added (aka 1-based index)
```

Comment: You don't really need `a = (str(summm))` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for i in range(len(sizes))` . I think it's the fastest solution, but I'm sure it doesn't matter.

```
def save(sizes, hd):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(sizes)):     # i values are 0,1,2,...,len(sizes)-1
        sum += sizes[i]             # add i-th sizes element to sum
        if sum <= hd:               # check if we can print answer
            print(i + 1)            # because i starts from 0
        else:                       # if we can't print, we should exit cycle
            break                   # we can use return instead
```

By the way, you don't need to do anything like this, because 'print()' function converts all arguments to str()

```
a = str(sum)
print(a)
```

I hope, you has learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
def save(sizes, hd):
    sum = 0
    new_list = []
    for i in sizes:
        sum += i
        new_list.append(i)
        if sum >= hd:
            print(new_list)
            return len(new_list)


print(save([4,4,4,3,3], 12))
#print(new_list) => [4, 4, 4]
#return len(new_list) => 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build a list with the cumulative sum of your sorted numbers, the position of the target value will correspond to the maximum count of numbers that will fit within your target:

```
from bisect import bisect_right
from itertools import accumulate

numbers = [4,4,4,3,3]
target  = 12
maxCount = bisect_right(list(accumulate(sorted(numbers))),target)

print(maxCount) # 3
```

*The bisect module provides efficient search for an index in a sorted list (bisect_right). The itertools module provides a function (accumulate) to obtain the cumulative sum of numbers in a list*

Answer (score -1):

I changed your code around a bit to keep it simple:

```
def save(sizes, hd): 
    size_list = [] #instead of an int, let's use a list object to hold values
    for size in sizes:
        size_list.append(i) # add the size to the list
        if sum(size_list) <= hd: # check if sum of all values in list is <= hd
            return len(size_list) # return the number of sizes inside of list
```

hope this helps!